# Linq, from list of objects, create list of properties based on another property's value

Tags: c#, linq

I need to get a list of risePeriods where bitPos > 2.

```
class Bit
{           
  public int bitPos { get; set; }        
  public int risePeriod { get; set; }
}

List<Bit> dataBits;
```

I tried

```
IEnumerable<int> rpList = dataBits
    .Where(bit => bit.bitPos > 2)
    .Select(bit => bit.risePeriod);
```

and

```
IEnumerable<int> rpList = from bit in dataBits 
                          where bit.bitPos > 2 
                          select bit.risePeriod
```

as well as other ways, but each returns the entire dataBits list instead of just a list of risePeriods. This should be simple - right?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure? Try: `rpList = rpList.ToList()` or (if you want to replace the original list): `dataBits =  rpList.ToList()`

Comment: are you sure you are looking at the variable rpList and not dataBits for the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried this and it seems to be working fine, as I suspected as the syntax and logic looks correct. You could try adding a call to `ToList` which will make it more clear when inspected that it is a list of integers. If not, there must be something else going on here. Here's the code I suggest:

```
IEnumerable<int> rpList = dataBits
.Where(bit => bit.bitPos > 2)
.Select(bit => bit.risePeriod)
.ToList();
```

Comment: The .ToList() was the answer!